# how can disk be invisible for a moment

Tags: linux, hard-drive, boot, partitioning, sleep

I did try to run mony linux in PC ram 500MB disk 40GB cpu 1,5GHz
and sometimes after reboot linux like tinycore puppy partedmagic
after load kernel and initrd in one time it can not see disk folders
and another time it see all and boot perfect

I test partitions and no error it is like he boot from pendrive
and need to wait for example 5 seconds to usb power on pen
but it is disk standard hdd and S.M.A.R.T. is ok

how can this be ?

Comment: and i test it all with gparted partitiom magic and standard windows xp

Answer (score 1):

Gosh, your question is horribly written.

However, it seems like you want the system to delay actually booting after loading the kernel, to give your USB drive and other disks time to "settle."

You can accomplish this with the `rootdelay=XX` boot-time kernel command line parameter.  `rootwait` may also help.

You can temporarily specify these in GRUB, and then edit the GRUB menu entries to make them permanent.